# Declaring variables of abstract type in C++

Tags: c++

I'd want to define a general class with some functions and nested classes with virtual functions:

```
class c_foo {
    public:
        class c_subfoo {
            public:
                virtual int do_subfoo(void) = 0;
               
        };

        int do_foo(void);
};
```

The function *c_foo::do_foo()* would call functions in the nested class *c_foo::c_subfoo*:

```
int c_foo::do_foo(void) {
    c_subfoo subfoo;
    subfoo.do_subfoo();
    return 0;
};
```

However I *cannot declare variable 'subfoo' to be of abstract type 'c_foo::c_subfoo' because c_foo::c_subfoo::do_subfoo is a pure virtual function*.

How can I define *c_foo::do_foo()*, which is always the same for all derived classes and that calls *c_foo::c_subfoo* functions, without defining these *c_foo::c_subfoo* functions, which are different in each derived class?

Comment: You cannot make an instance of an abstract class. (That's the actual intention to make a class abstract - to prevent that it can be instanced accidentally.) If you intend to instance it - don't make it abstract. ;-) What you can do: working with references or pointers of that abstract class, so that you can apply your function to an instance of any derived class.

Comment: @Scheff What is the alternative to make it abstract? Should I use a dummy function for c_foo::c_subfoo::do_subfoo in the abstract class?

Comment: You're question is lacking a bit context. (I suspect an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).) Maybe, describe a bit more what you actually want to achieve. (Possible recommendations could be: Don't make it a class. Make the virtual function not pure. Don't make it a virtual function. Etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure** virtual function basically says: you **have** to override this function.
And override means you have to derive from c_subfoo and provide a different implementation.
And that means you cannot instantiate object of c_subfoo directly.

So this leaves you different options:

1.use pointer/reference to some subsubfoo, for ex.

```
c_subfoo* subfoo = somefactory::create_some_sub_subfoo();

subfoo->do_subfoo(); // now use virtual dispatch 

(of course, you would rather use smart pointers instead of raw pointers)
```

or

2. dont use **pure** virtual

or

3. maybe you could make those functions static, if they dont need an object to operate  on

or

4.maybe you could use static polymorphism (as CRTP[)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
template <typename SubFoo>
class c_foo : public SubFoo
{
...
   void do_foo()
   {
      ...
      SubFoo::do_subfoo();
      ...
   }
};

class c_subfoo : public c_foo<c_subfoo>
{
...
   void do_subfoo()
   {...}
}
```

As a side note regarding your question:

if a class is nested or not doesn't play any role in this case. It only affects the visibility/namespace of inner class, but not it's virtual(or pure virtual) behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use [inheritance](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus13.html)? Make `c_subfoo` a class that derives from `c_foo`.